# changing image opacity in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

bellow is my attempt to change the opacity of the image using a slider widget in jquery mobile. But so far with this code nothing happens. What is wrong with my code? thank

the script:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
    <head> 
        <title>Base template</title> 
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.css" />
        <script src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js">

          $(document).ready(function(){
           $('#slider-0').click(function(){
            $("img").fadeTo(1000,0.4);
             });
             });
        </script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-role="header">
         <h3>Change image opacity</h3>
        </div>
          <div data-role="content" class="ui-content">
            <label for="slider-0">Input slider:</label>
            <input type="range" name="slider-0" id="slider-0" value="60" min="0" max="100" />
            <img src="images/int-mountain-day.jpg" />
          </div>


    </body> 
    </html>
```

Comment: $('img').css('opacity', '0.5');

Comment: you're using an obsolete version of jQM, upgrade to 1.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to listen onchange event and then use input value to set new opacity:

```
$(function() {
    $('#slider-0').change(function () {
        $("img").stop(true).fadeTo(1000, this.value / 100);
    });
});
```

Note: you need to divide value by 100 to fit in 0-1 range. You also need to stop any currently running opacity animations with `.stop` method.

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/xzssb5y6/1

**UPD**. @Omar in comments makes a valid point that instead usual `$(function() {})` document ready wrapper, it's more reliable to use jQuery Mobile `pagecreate` event:

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", "#page2", function () {
    $('#slider-0').change(function () {
        $("img").stop(true).fadeTo(1000, this.value / 100);
    });        
});
```

Comment: Good Answer +1! As you are using a slider, it is probably best to set the animation duration to 0 so you get instant response: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/xzssb5y6/2/

Comment: @ezanker I think OP wants nice transition effect, that's why there is `fadeTo` animation method. Otherwise simple `css('opacity', this.value / 100)` would work, no need of `fadeTo` at all.

Comment: I'm sorry but when I copy paste your script nothing happens!

Comment: Make sure you wrap my code with `$(function() { $('#slider').change(...); })`. Your script block is before actual HTML it's working with, so event is not registered, because there is no target element. See updated answer.

Comment: @dfsq code should be wrapped in `$(document).on("pagecreate", "#pageID", function () {});` not `.ready()`.

Comment: @Omar I think that in this case document ready also works fine, because we just want to bind onchange event.

Comment: Your code will work in one case, if the element is within "first page". `.ready()` fires once per document, `pagecreate` fires once per page. http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/7d38o83y/

Comment: @Omar I see what you mean, you are right. I will update the answer, in case OP returns with this problem. However this question was more about opacity on change. But thank you for this valid point.